# How to add ampersand (&) at the end of HttpContent

Tags: c#, .net

One of the websites I'm sending a Post request has a single ampersand (&) at the end of the Post Data thats sent with the Post request.

How to I append an & to the end of the Post Data when using HttpContent?

Here's an example of the code:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user", userid));
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password));

HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsync("https://www.site.com/login", content);
```

The Post Data sent needs to look like:

```
username=324234&password=12345&
```

It's odd there is an & at the end of the request, but without it the request fails.

Please note, this is NOT an & at the end of the 'password' field. If I was to add that, it would encode the &. The & is sent with every request regardless of the password used.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're going to vote down please explain why.

Comment: Put an ampersand on the end of your password? That's basically what your example looks like

Comment: No, it's not at the end of the password, it's an empty key/value. Oh heck I just answered my own question! Thank you @CDspace

Comment: Oh that failed because it then adds &= I'll edit the question.

Comment: I believe this question is so specific to your case  that will not help others and you should delete it. Thanks

Comment: Excuse me? I'm asking how to manually add an & to the end of the Post Data. If PostAsync accepted a string as the second parameter it'd be easy, but because it only accepts HttpContent, and I'm using a KeyValuePair it's a little tricky and I'm looking for possible solutions.

Comment: @LuisFilipe, how can you be so sure no one will ever have the same issue? It's perfectly valid question and there is no reason to delete it.

Comment: I wonder if you added a dummy field would it accept it (either way, it looks like you're having to workaround a bug on the server, from this).

Comment: Just my understanding but it seems I am wrong; My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormUrlEncodedContent` doesn't support this, but you can always add the final '&' yourself and send the result as a `StringContent`:

```
HttpContent content = await new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData)
                                .WithFinalAmpersandAsync();

...

static class HttpContentExtensions
{
    public static async Task<HttpContent> WithFinalAmpersandAsync(
        this FormUrlEncodedContent formUrlEncodedContent)
    {
        string content = await formUrlEncodedContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return new StringContent(content + "&");
    }
}
```